# How can I show alert dialog after axios http methods?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to add color by using the post method with axios in react. The backend side works very well. I can add a color, but I want an alert dialog to appear on the screen. if an error is encountered then show an error message when adding . Every time I press the button, it doesn't work, only if the axios operation is successful, the successful alert dialog will appear. If there is an error, the error alert dialgo should appear. I'm new to react so I dont know actually how to apply it my codes.

**AddColor.js**

```
import axios from "axios"
import { useState } from "react";


export default function AddColor() {


    const [Name, setcolorName] = useState('');
   

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {

        e.preventDefault();

        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'http://localhost:64082/api/color/add',
            data: {
                Name
            }
        })
        

    }


    return (

        <div className="create">
            <h2>Add a New Color</h2>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <label>color Name:</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    required
                    value={Name}
                    placeholder="please enter color name..."
                    onChange={(e) => setcolorName(e.target.value)}
                />

                <button>Add Category</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )

}
```

Comment: How are you displaying a *successful alert dialog* ?

Comment: yes I 'm trying to display alert dialog (succesfull and error) like this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/alerts/     after axios http methods for example post method like above or get method it doesnt matter

Comment: I would suggest type="submit" to the button inside the form.

Comment: the form is already running handlesubmit. How exactly can I do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/embed/condescending-goldwasser-fv6o2v?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) to explain to you how to do it using `async/await` syntax. I will paste the results here.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default function App() {
  const [Name, setcolorName] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      await axios({
        method: "post",
        url: "https://httpstat.us/200",
        data: {
          Name
        }
      });
      return alert("Success!");
    } catch (error) {
      return alert("Error: " + error);
    }

  };

  return ( ...
```

Comment: It's not the alertdialog I want but this will work too, thank you @Caio Gomes

Comment: Ok! I saw the other comment just now. If you have trouble implementing it later, hit me up with another comment and I can help you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the axios `.then` and `.catch` to update your states and show popup in function.

```js
axios({
   method: 'post',
   url: 'http://localhost:64082/api/color/add',
   data: {
      Name
   }
})
.then((res) => {
   // here show your success popup
})
.catch((err) => {
   // here show your error popup
})
```

Comment: Can you give an example for the success popup part?

Comment: I tried but nothing appeared on the screen. properly added to the database

Answer (score 0):

Axios has a method called `.catch()` ([link](https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors)).

```
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'http://localhost:64082/api/color/add',
    data: {
        Name
    }
}).catch((error) => {
    console.alert(error.response.data || "Code 500: Internal Server Error")
})
```

Comment: I don't want to show it in the console, I want to show it to the user like this    https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/alerts/